# Getting information of a pdf

Tags: string, pdf, time, get

I have run into a little problem. Basicly i want to exstract from String-data off a pdf file.
More specifik this pdf file

http://www.midttrafik.dk/koereplaner/bybusser/aarhus/bybusser-aarhus/18-mejlbyelev-park-all%C3%A9-skaade-moesgaard/koereplan

So, my problem lays in not knowing, how to get the names, and the times(the pdf is times and locations of bus-stops, street names on the left kolon, and bus ariving times is the rest). the info i want to save is the number befor the street name (1-4), the street name, and all of the times.

translate of some of the stuff on the pdf.
Faste minuttal - just means that bus times is the same for the intival under 'Faste 
6.56 - 8.11 - this means that, in this intival followes the under.
so
the buss will stop at 'Elev Skole, Høvej' 56, 11, 26, 41 meaning 6.56, 7.11, 7.26, 7.41, 7.56, 8.11.

I dont think i can desribe my problem any better, so i hope one of you guys will be able to help. i dont need a ready code, just send me in the rigth direaction - tell me what i can do, that migth help, or good patterns to use. 
Thanks

Comment: Which programming environment?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the nice PDFBox Library from here to extract the text you want from this pdf file. It works really nice, i used it in one of my last projects to index pfd files for a full text search.

Here is the URL to the project: 
http://pdfbox.apache.org/index.html

There you'll find also the documentation and some examples how to extract text from pdf's.

Sample Code:

```
import java.io.*;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.*;
import org.apache.pdfbox.util.*;

public class LittleExample {

 public static void main(String[] args){

 PDDocument pd;
 BufferedWriter wr;
 try {
         // this is your pdf from which you would like to extract the text
         File input = new File("/home/ottp/pdffiles/1.pdf");
         // this is the target file to store the extracted text
         File output = new File("/home/ottp/pdffiles/extracts/1.txt"); 
         pd = PDDocument.load(input);
         System.out.println(pd.getNumberOfPages());
         System.out.println(pd.isEncrypted());

         pd.save("CopyOfInvoice.pdf")
         PDFTextStripper stripper = new PDFTextStripper();
         wr = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(output)));
         stripper.writeText(pd, wr);
         if (pd != null) {
             pd.close();
         }
        // close and flush the output stream
        wr.close();
 } catch (Exception e){
         e.printStackTrace();
        }
     }
}
```